# Generating Plot in Tikz from Text File

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am trying to learn how to generate a plot given coordinates specificied in a text file, for example, the latex code in:

https://github.com/daleroberts/obstacle-problem/blob/master/figures/fig1.tex

refers to the text file:

https://github.com/daleroberts/obstacle-problem/blob/master/figures/obstacle1d-0.table

but I'm not quite sure how to get this working on my own latex environment, it doesn't seem to read in the coordinates from the text file. Is it a directory issue or do I need to add something to the code?

Comment: Just save both files into the same folder.  Do not change the filenames until you verify they work  unless you edit the *.tex as needed for the new filename. Then use pdflatex to compile fig1.tex.  Having done this, it compiles fine.

Comment: @R.Schumacher so do you go to "raw" then copy paste into a text file and name it "obstacle1d-1.table " ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a PGFPLOTS solution:

[image]

The files fig1.tex, obstacle1d-0.table and obstacle1d-1.table are in the same folder.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-1:1,
    xmin=-1.6, xmax=1.6,
    ymin=-0.6, ymax=1.2,
    axis lines=center,
    axis equal image,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ]
    \addplot[smooth] table {obstacle1d-0.table}
        node[right] {$g(x)$};
    \addplot[very thick,color=red] table {obstacle1d-1.table}
        node[above right] {$v(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, I'm still confused though since I saved the text file in the same folder as the latex file with the code in your answer, but I just get an error.. Not sure how to store the text file properly

Comment: @dimebucker91 What's the error?

Comment: To store the text file: right-click the "Raw" button and select "save target as...".

Comment: ah... seems silly now, thanks a lot, the original code works, although i get an error with the code in the solution, the error says "Could not read table file ..."

Comment: @dimebucker91 You are welcome. Double check the filename.

Comment: Oh, I see, in the github solution, they use two different data files, obstacle1d-0.table and obstacle1d-1.table.

Comment: @dimebucker91 See the update.